# decodeAudioData example does not work on Safari

Tags: safari, web-audio-api

I tried to use decodeAudioData on Safari but failed. Searching for a solution I found that even

https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/decode-audio-data/

does not work on safari (Version 11.0.2 (11604.4.7.1.6) on OSX 10.11.6)

For details see https://github.com/mdn/webaudio-examples/issues/5

Is there any workaround available?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AudioContext.decodeAudioData(...) not working on iPhone but working everywhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489787/audiocontext-decodeaudiodata-not-working-on-iphone-but-working-everywhere-e)